# throwing error while creating production build when using npm install --production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package.json, next.js

I have installed `brotli-webpack-plugin` as a `devDependency`. While trying to create production build using `npm run build` (internally it calls `next build`), it throws following error

> Error: Cannot find module 'brotli-webpack-plugin'.

I am using this plugin inside `next.config.js`.

During my production build, I want to do `npm install --production` to reduce the container size. What should I do ?

If i use `npm istall` only, then the build is being created without any error. Should I move that package from `devDependency` to `dependency` ?

Comment: please add more details to the question. At the least add a repro repo

Comment: If I install both dependency and devDependency, then I am able to create the build. But if I install only dependency, then the build process is throwing `Error: Cannot find module 'brotli-webpack-plugin'`.  This package has been added as a devDependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to do this:

1. Install dependencies.
2. Build app
3. Create container ( I assume you are using Docker for containerisation )

And you want to add only the production dependencies. The module that throws you the error is needed in build phase and if you install only production dependencies the build won't succeed. Assuming you are using a terminal or anything with bash do something like this:

1. rm -rf node_modules ( this cleans your dependencies )
2. npm install ( install all dependencies )
3. npm build ( or any of your build commands )
4. rm -rf node_modules ( here you clean again the dependencies because you already have the build done )
5. npm install --production ( there you have it - dependencies only for production )
6. Whatever command which creates your docker container

Should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want do `npm install` twice. Anyway, I am trying your solution.